How can most probable velocity of a gas be zero if there is essentially no molecule having zero speed?
Most probable velocity of a gas is zero but most probable speed is definately not zero.In fact,A gas will have nearly zero molecules that is standing still. Then, how can most probable velocity be zero if  speed is just the magnitute of velocity.What's the intuition behind this?

speed is a scalar whereas velocity is a vector (or a signed quantity in 1d).

$1+(-1)=0$, but $|1|+|-1|=1+1=2$

I think I see what you are asking, but you could edit your question to make this clearer. We expect the kinetic energies to follow a Boltzmann distribution i.e. $P(E) \propto \exp(-E/kT)$, and since $E = \frac12m|v|^2$ we get $P(|v|) \propto \exp(-m|v|^2/2kT)$. Then since $P(|v|)$ peaks at zero how is it that (in three dimensions) the speed distribution does not peak at zero? Have I understood you correctly?

There are ‘essentially’ no molecules having any given non-zero speed as well.

@JohnRennie Thanks, But I do think I understand the mathematical reason for the speed distribution curve to not peak at zero.Because, in in the velocity space, there are multiple points for which we get the same speed and to account for that we multiply it by the volume of a spherical shell in the v-space $4\pi r^2 dv $. And the result v^2*exp(−m|v|2/2kT) is not symmetric about the y axis, right?

I will answer what I think you are asking. If I have misunderstood you then ignore this answer.
For a gas in equilibrium we expect the kinetic energies to follow a Boltzmann distribution:
$$ P(E) \propto e^{−E/kT} $$
and since $E=\frac12mv^2$ we get:
$$ P(v) \propto e^{−mv^2/2kT} $$
Then since $P(v)$  peaks at zero how is it that (in three dimensions) the speed distribution does not peak at zero?
The answer is that the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution does not give the probability that a molecule has the speed $v$. In fact, as another answer has noted, the probability that the speed is exactly $v$  is zero. The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution gives the probability that the speed lies in the range from $v$ to $v+dv$.
The reason for the $v^2$ term is that the number of particles with a speed in the range $v\to v+dv$ increases quadratically with $v$. Mathematically this is because the volume of the phase space increases quadratically with $v$, though this probably isn't what you'd consider an intuitive answer.
To try and get a feel for this imagine that we write a velocity as $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ where the components $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ are quantised so they can only take integer values. Now there is only one way to get a velocity of zero i.e. $(0,0,0)$.
Suppose we take the range $v = 0 \to 1$. There are six ways to do this: $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$ and finally $(0,0,-1)$.
And now the range $v=1\to2$. There are the six ways to do this, $(2,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, $(0,0,2)$, $(-2,0,0)$, $(0,-2,0)$ and $(0,0,-2)$, but also $(1,1,0)$ and all the other permutations of two $1$s and a zero. So there are more ways to have a velocity in the range $1\to2$ than there are ways to have a velocity in the range $0\to1$. If we go up to $v=2\to3$ the number of ways increases again, and it keeps increasing as we keep increasing $v$.
Obviously requiring the components of a velocity be an integer isn't realistic, but we can take the quantisation to be some value $a$ and look at the limit where $a\to0$, and if we do this we find the number of velocities in the range $v\to v+dv$ increases quadratically with $v$, and that's how we get the $v^2$ term in the distribution.

By most probable velocity I  meant the peak of the velocity distribution curve, where N(v) is proportional to exp(-mv^2 / 2KT),  ( without any v^2 factor as in speed distribution curve). This relation is true at least for individual components, right?

Thanks for the edit. I think I do understand that we get the $v^2$ term by taking the volume of a spherical shell $4\pi v^2 dv$ in the velocity space as this volume consists all  the velocities that gives us the required speed. But the fact that the most probable velocity of the gas molecules is zero ( from the relation $P(v)∝e−mv2/2kT$) while there is no molecule with zero velocity still seems nonintuitive to me.

Clearly, molecules in a box have to have a vanishing ($=0$) mean speed, just for symmetry reasons, otherwise the box would have a preferred direction. So first of all, we need to have a distribution where in each dimension (x, y, z..) the negative velocity is as likely as the positive one. So for example in 1D the distribution of $v_x$ is $P\sim e^{-v^2_x}$ and that is a bell-shaped curved peaked at 0.
Notice however that velocity is signed, can be positive or negative and needs on average to have no preferred direction. Speed (the absolute value of the velocity) is positive and its distribution is not peaked at 0 but at a positive value! So indeed if you sample not the direction of motion in x, y, z but the speed then you are right: it is not peaked in 0. The distribution of $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$ is given by $P\approx v^2e^{-v^2}$ and if you plot it you will see is it not peaked at 0.
Or maybe, your question is why is the velocity distribution a Gaussian distribution i.e., one with a peak in the center, and not another one. Indeed (say, in one dimension for simplicity), even a distribution $P$ with to symmetrical peaks at $\pm v_p$ and with $P(0)=0$ would satisfy the condition that $\langle v \rangle =0$.
The answer sadly is in the maths. The derivation of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution turns out to be a normal distribution, with $0$ being the most likely speed. So your intuition that "A gas will have nearly zero molecules that is standing still" is wrong: if you take molecules one by one out of the box and measure their speed you will get a lot of values close to zero.
One intuition might be that a molecule going at speed $+v$ at some point due to various collision will revert its speed to $-v$ and by doing so it crosses all the values between $-v$ and $+v$, and sometimes it is "trapped" in values close to $v=0$ i.e. it oscillates a lot around the zero speed due to "collisions" etc. etc. Remember that by the law of great numbers a lot of small effects ("collision") almost always average to a Gaussian distribution, so that's what is happening here: a lot of collisions randomize the molecules and the net effect is a Gaussian.
Another intuition one would be that molecules tend to have a very low speed, with higher speeds becoming less and less likely and that's why the peak is at 0.  Notice, that the peak close to 0 does not mean that a lot of molecules are "immobile", just that they have very low speed, close to 0, and the probability of finding molecules with speed $0\pm dv$ is higher than any other value. The probability of a molecule having exactly zero speed is undefined!
But in the end: it is just how it is.
In other words: this is the distribution that maximizes entropy! There's not much more to say about it, it's just how it is! The "two-peaks" distribution we assumed might have been possible but it is found to be "less likely" by the theory which in turns favors the one-peaked, Maxwell-Boltzmann one! It's just the most natural ways for the molecules in a gas to be.

Im not certain of what your definition of 'most probable' is (edit: as you've made clear you mean the mode of the function). We take that the velocity of some particle in 1 Dimension is given by the distribution $f(v)$.
The mode refers to the location of the distribution which is the highest point. Another way of writing this is that the maximum likelihood is given by,
$$v_{ML} = argmax{f(v)}$$
The story here is less clear than in the mean method but in general you will expect the mode in 1D,m speed and velocity will be the same up to a sign.
For example if the allowed values of v = [-1, 0, 1] and f(v) = [0.7,0,0.5], then, $v_{ML} = 1$ and $s_{ML} = 1$
In the case where we have a continuous random variable $X$ described by $f(x)$ then we can describe the velocity by 3 random variables. The speed then is a function of 3 random variables $Y = \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2}$.
If you compute the probability distribution of this variable $Y$, in this case we assume that $f(x) = e^{-\alpha x^2}$, we obtain the distribution of the random variable $Y$, $$f(r) \sim r^2 e^{-\alpha r^2}$$
We find then that while the individual random variables $X$ have MLE zero (gaussian is maximized at $x=0$, $Y$ can have any MLE in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Intuative explanation
This explanation is basically just application of statistics, the intuitive takeaway here you can get from the fact that in 1D you don't see this, or rather the reason the distribution of $Y$ as MLE non zero is basically because of the $r^2$ term. This tells us that the reason the MLE is non zero for speed is basically because there is a higher 'density of states' at higher velocities, or if you like there is a higher density of states at higher velocities for free particles at least.

By most probable velocity I meant the peak of the velocity distribution curve, where N(v_x) is proportional to exp(-m v_x^2 / 2KT). As this distribution is symmetric with respect to the Y axis, the peak lies at x=0, Right? That is what I asked about!

Ah ok! this is what would usually be described as the mode of the distribution, I incorrectly called it the maximum likelihood, but I've amended my question to try to answer better.

Essentially no molecules have a speed of precisely $0$ or any other precise number. But some have a speed within $1$ m/s of $0$. And more are close to $0$ than any other speed.

This seems to me to be in fact directly (and definitively) responsive to the OP's question.

Yes, this is a bit weird. I think the easiest way to see this is to plot the relevant functions. The probability distribution for the velocity, $\vec v=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ is $$P(v_x,v_y,v_z)=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi \ k_B \ T} \right)^{3/2} \ \exp\left( -\frac{m}{k_B \ T} (v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)\right)$$
Plotting a 3D probability density is difficult, so I will plot it with $v_z=0$, but please remember that the third dimension exists. So the plot of the probability density function is 
As you correctly pointed out, this probability density function has a mode at $\vec v=0$. However, you must remember that this is a probability density function. You do not get a probability until you integrate it over some region in $v_x$, $v_y$, and $v_z$.
To visualize this more concretely, let's plot the previous graph as a contour plot
. Notice that the ring labeled 0.06 encloses about 1/4 of the area of the ring labeled 0.05. So, although the probability density is slightly higher in the 0.06 ring, because the area is so much larger in the 0.05 ring, the integrated probability is actually higher.
If you actually do the integration along spherical shells (in all 3 dimensions) you get the probability distribution for the speed $v=|\vec v|=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$: $$P(v)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(\frac{m}{k_B \ T} \right)^{3/2}v^2 \exp \left(-\frac{m}{2 \ k_B \ T} v \right)$$
Graphically this is:

So this is still a probability density function, but now it is integrated over spherical shells of radius $|\vec v|$ representing the speed. Because the surface area of these shells gets larger faster than the probability density function on $\vec v$ decreases, you get an increase in $P(v)$ going outwards from $\vec v=0$.
So the magnitude of the most probable velocity is not the same as the most probable speed.
